# German online comprehension sites?

Tags: vocabulary, online-resource, listening-comprehension

I am practicing my German for a trip to Germany next month and I'm trying to get as much practice as I can. Can anybody recommend any online sites (or YouTube channels, or whatever) that offer quality comprehension exercises? I have plenty of books and read the newspaper so I'm looking more for auditory comprehension. In addition does anybody have any online vocabulary resources for an intermediate learner? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean actual *exercises* (e.g. you get some input, then solve some questions about it) or just intermediate listening materials?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Exercises will help more for sure, but any sources you have to offer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Deutsche Welle has many resources, e.g.

  - the YouTube playlist [Deutsch lernen mit Videos (Niveau B2/C1)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5113EDF7E1116D32), which contains over 200 videos!
  - [News broadcast that are spoken at a slower pace](http://www.dw.com/de/04032016-langsam-gesprochene-nachrichten/a-19093563).
  - [Alltagsdeutsch](http://www.dw.com/de/deutsch-lernen/alltagsdeutsch/s-9214) focuses on everyday language.
- The YouTube channel [Easy German](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbxb2fqe9oNgglAoYqsYOtQ) has over 150 short videos with street interviews and similar activities that show how German is really used.
- The YouTube channel [Deutsch Global](http://www.youtube.com/user/deutschglobal) teaches German (elementary to intermediate) in German.

You can find more links on [my website](http://cstrobbe.github.io/languagelearning/german/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://www.duolingo.com ... sign up for their German course, and do the initial assessment.